# Type guards checking for property existence

Tags: typescript

I know [type guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) can be used to distinguish between unioned types. But is it possible to detect property existence on an unknown type being passed in?

This code does not work.

```
function foo(bar: unknown | { createdDate: Date }) {
    if (bar.createdDate)
        alert(bar.createdDate); //Doesn't work
}
```

Neither does this:

```
function foo(bar: unknown | { createdDate: Date }) {
    if ('createdDate' in bar)
        alert(bar.createdDate); //Doesn't work
}
```

Note: Changing the type of `bar` to `any` does work, but the compiler is not narrowing the type inside the `if` statement. It is typing `bar.createdDate` as `any`.

I've also tried generic versions of this function to avail.

```
function foo<T extends (unknown | { createdDate: Date })>(bar: T) {
    if ('createdDate' in bar)
        alert(bar.createdDate); //Doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way to confirm existence of a property on an unknown type and then have the compiler narrow the type appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a union `unknown` "eats up" any other members, so `unknown | { createdDate: Date } == unknown` (this behavior is described [in the PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439))

Also from the PR, `unknown` can be narrowed in the following ways:

```
function f20(x: unknown) {
    if (typeof x === "string" || typeof x === "number") {
        x;  // string | number
    }
    if (x instanceof Error) {
        x;  // Error
    }
    if (isFunction(x)) {
        x;  // Function
    }
}
```

It would appear the only way to achieve the outcome you want is using a custom type guard (since `typeof x === "typename" is not applicable and`instanceof` does not work with interfaces)

```
function foo(bar: unknown) {
  const hasCreatedDate = (u: any): u is { createdDate: Date } => "createdDate" in u;
  if (hasCreatedDate(bar)) {
    alert(bar.createdDate);
  }
}
```

Or you can use `Object` which will not eat up any other union members

```
function foo(bar: Object | { createdDate: Date }) {
  if ("createdDate" in bar) {
    alert(bar.createdDate); 
  }
}

foo({aa: ""})
```

Comment: There are also some [open](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25720) [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) about this

Comment: @artem Those look like nice to have suggestions, hope `in` type guard becomes stronger, unfortunately I don't think either will fully help with this exact use case since (at least from my reading) OP would expect `bar.createdDate` to be `Date` and this information is lost because of the way `unknown` works in unions

Comment: Your solution with object works well, thanks. Though I think it would be better as `Object` and not `object` so that its as permissive as possible.

Comment: @MgSam changed to `Object`

Comment: Well I would expect `if ((typeof bar === 'object') && (bar !== null) &&  ('createdDate' in bar))` to work after all related issues are fixed